# Using a Select to display more than one data type after a fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently fetching data for my app from an api for one country - 'germany':

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await fetchDataByCountry("germany");
      setData(data);
      console.log(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

This returns a result in the following:

```
return (
    <div className="container">
      <Country />
      <Cases cases={data.cases} />
      <Deaths deaths={data.deaths} />
      <Recovered recovered={data.recovered} />
      <TodayCases todayCases={data.todayCases} />
      <TodayDeaths todayDeaths={data.todayDeaths} />
    </div>
  );
```

This currently works fine, but I want to add another country - uk and make it possible to change between the two to compare data using a 'select'. I came up with this, but it doesn't work:

```
const Country = () => {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState('');

    return (
    <form>
        <select name="country" id="country"
            value={ country }
            onChange={e => setCountry(e.target.value)}
        >
            <option value="">Choose a country</option>
            <option value="germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="uk">UK</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    );
}
```

How can this be refactored to get the result I want???

Comment: You need to change onChange function to set a new set of data. 
So instead of using useEffect which happens at component mount time, you can call fetch data again. maybe pass a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, but in the end I did this in the index.js:

```
 // ! Initialises state
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('Germany');

  // ! Fetch data by country on intial mount and for every change in the selected country
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async country => {
      const data = await fetchDataByCountry(country);
      setData(data);
      console.log(data);
    };
    fetchData(country);
  }, [country]);
```

For the Country.js, which contains the Select I did this:

```
const Country = (props) => {
   const {country, handleCountryChange} = props;
    return (
        <form>
            <select name="country" id="country"
                value={ country }
                onChange={e => handleCountryChange(e.target.value)}
            >
                <option value="">Choose a country</option>
                <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                <option value="UK">UK</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    );
}
```

And what gets returned in the index.js is this:

```
return (
    <div className="container">
      <Country country={country} handleCountryChange={setCountry} />
      <Cases cases={data.cases} />
      <Deaths deaths={data.deaths} />
      <Recovered recovered={data.recovered} />
      <TodayCases todayCases={data.todayCases} />
      <TodayDeaths todayDeaths={data.todayDeaths} />
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this on calling the fetch when the state of `country` is changed:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await fetchDataByCountry(country);
      setData(data);
      console.log(data);
    };
    fetchData();
}, [country]);   // <- Execute useEffect body when country value is changed
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work for you.

```
 const fetchData = async (country) => {
      const data = await fetchDataByCountry(country);
      setData(data);
      console.log(data);
 };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData("Germany");
  }, []);

  const Country = () => {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState('');

    return (
    <form>
        <select name="country" id="country"
            value={ country }
            onChange={e => fetchData(e.target.value)}
        >
            <option value="">Choose a country</option>
            <option value="germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="uk">UK</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    );
}
```

So basically onChange we will refetch the data using the new country that will set the state and cause a rerender.

Can't really test it without all other components. But let me know if this works for you. If all of these are nested components you can pass functions down this way.